# epigraph relative interior not included

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis

> Let $f$ be a convex function from $\mathbb R^{d}$ to $\mathbb R$. Why is the point $\big(x_0,f(x_0)\big)$ not in the relative interior of epigraph of $f$?

I know it is not in interior but why not in relative interior as well where we consider the affine hull of the epigraph of function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e_1$, $\dots$, $e_d$ be unit vectors in the directions of the axes.  Then the epigraph contains points $(x_0+e_i,f(x_0+e_i))$ ($i=1$, $\dots$, $d$) and $(x_0,f(x_0)+1)$.  Therefore, its affine hull is all of ${\Bbb R}^{d+1}$, so the relative interior is the same as the interior.

Comment: If instead $f \colon E \to (- \infty, \infty]$ is proper, convex and lower semicontinuous and $E$ is a Banach space, does the result still hold?